# Meteor.js: How to dynamically route while limiting subscription?

Tags: collections, meteor, router, subscription

I'm trying to route to one page if something exists, and another if it doesn't. However, I don't want to subscribe to the entire collection (~thousands), because I think it will affect performance. How do I do this?

I tried something like this, but for some reason Meteor goes through the router code twice on pageload and flashes the error page briefly before redirecting to the item page, and I don't want this to happen.

Here's what I have:

router.coffee

```
to: (id)->
  Meteor.subscribe 'item', id
  item = Items.findOne id
  if item
    # if the item exists, then redirect to it
    Session.set 'currentItemId', id
    'itemPage'
  else
    # if not, then redirect to the sorry page
    'sorryPage'
```

publications.coffee

```
Meteor.publish 'item', (id)->
  return Items.find({_id: id})
```

Subscribing to the entire collection will affect performance, right? Is there an easier way to check existence within a collection without subscribing to it? I tried to do a Meteor.call to check it server side, but it didn't work and isn't ideal (router waiting on server call..). Is there a "right" way to do this?

Comment: The functionality you ask for is built in the iron-router (http://www.paypertise.com/meteorjs/iron-router-tutorial), you should consider using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this "flashing" effect is probably because your router is implemented to be reactive (I'm not sure if this is a right strategy BTW) and since you're using `Items.findOne`, this method invalidates the current computation as soon as the data requested by `Meteor.subscribe` arrives to the `Items` collection.

Also, note that every subscription within an active computation get's cancelled automatically as soon as the computation gets recomputed. However, as it is claimed in the documenation (look [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe)) `Meteor` should be smart enough to detect when you subscribe to the same data set twice, so this should not have any side effects.

If I were you, I would consider changing my router logic to something like this:

```
Session.set('currentItemId', id);
var status = Session.get('currentItemStatus');    
if (status === 'ready')
    return 'itemPage';
if (status === 'missing')
    return 'sorryPage';
return 'loadingPage'; // probably status === 'loading'
```

And then, somewhere else in the project I would do:

```
Deps.autorun(function () {
    Session.set('currentItemStatus', 'loading');  
    Meteor.subscribe('item', Session.get('currentItemId'), function () {
        // onReady callback
        var item = Items.findOne({_id:id});
        if (item)
            Session.set('currentItemStatus', 'ready');
        else
            Session.set('currentItemStatus', 'missing');
    });
});
```

Please note, that if `currentItemId` does not change, the computation defined `Deps.autorun` will not be invalidated, so no unnecessary `loadingPage` will be shown to the user.

Comment: I ended up switching to iron-router, but this is the solution to the question I asked. Thanks!